Why does reverse DNS lookup fail with timeout?
I have several IPs that can't be lookup. E.x.
nslookup 212.110.132.13 
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 8.8.8.8, trying next server
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.53
** server can't find 13.132.110.212.in-addr.arpa: SERVFAIL

Sometimes it fails with SERVFAIL, sometimes with timed out.
What I've Tried:

Tested different DNS servers, including Google DNS (8.8.8.8).
Checked network configurations and firewall settings.
Verified that other IP addresses resolve without issues.

Questions:

What could be causing these inconsistent DNS resolution failures?
Are there any additional troubleshooting steps I can take to identify the root cause?


As @Giacomo1968 mentions, it's not yet found on some DNS servers, though it does show on WhoIs: https://www.whois.com/whois/212.110.132.13 . Try yet another DNS resolver, such as Cloudflare, 1.1.1.1 , or wait a it and try again.

Clouditalia, the owner of that netblock (block of IPv4 addresses), or some smaller customer that Clouditalia assigned that section of that netblock to (maybe wnet.ua?), does not seem to have correctly set up reverse DNS records for that part of that netblock.
13.132.119.212.in-addr.arpa lacks even a Name Server (NS) or Start of Authority (SOA) record, so the domain name system cannot even locate an authoritative name server to send the query to.
Thus, a server can't be found, so the query times out and generates a SERVFAIL.

This doesn't really make sense. If there was no NS delegation, the authoritative server of the parent zone would just return "No such name, NXDOMAIN" when queried, as happens with ordinary subdomains. (And dnstracer says there is a delegation at 132.119.212.in-addr.arpa to Tele2's dns.swip.net servers, which return an actual PTR response...)

I tried several different DNS servers, but none of them could resolve the address. Can I assume there's nothing I can do on my end? As I understand it, a SERVFAIL response isn't even cached locally. The best I can do might be to reduce the timeouts for resolution.

@YevhenSurovskyi Unless you own these IP addresses, there's nothing for you to do. Something's wrong on the server side.

Timeout is just that your PC didn't get any response in time. For example, it could be temporary network issues like internet slowness or packet loss (DNS is UDP, and can easily miss responses now and then). Often, the server has to do more lookups on its end and doesn't get back to you soon enough.
In the case with your example IP 212.110.132.13, the referral servers regularly take 8+ seconds to reply for some reason (checking with MXToolBox transcript), so they could be having some issues

SERVFAIL is because the server itself failed to get a response from whatever upstream servers it checks. This can be anything between it and and the next server, like network issues/dnssec failures/server overloaded/etc. The error message does not specify, so you have no way of knowing from the client side.
The general solution for intermittent issues is to have two or more DNS servers configured (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for Google, or 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 for CloudFlare etc), but that won't solve issues with the propagation.
